# Mapping stored procedures to views

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern

I have the problem with the mapping a stored procedure to an EF entity which is represented by the view in the database.

If I try to call, for example, an `.Add` method - get the error

> Too many parameters ...

I know/understand, that EF wants all parameters of the entity except keys (+computed) in the mapped Add - stored procedure. But in the case of "entity = view", I want to post as stored procedure parameters only some set of EF entity fields, which I have in db table (one field set in the case of insert, another set in the case of update, third set in the case of delete).

How to do this "right"? In `.edmx` this (mapping via graphic interface) works perfectly but I need to realize this behavior in the code-first by hands..

Example:

View in DB ..

```
CREATE VIEW vDepartment
AS
    SELECT 
        d.*, 
        dp.Code as ParentCode, dp.SName as ParentSName, 
        dp.Name as ParentName 
    FROM 
        Department d
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        Department dp ON d.ParentID = dp.ID
```

EF entity

```
public partial class vDepartment
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> ParentID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string SName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CloseDate { get; set; }
    public string ParentCode { get; set; }
    public string ParentSName { get; set; }
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping ..

```
modelBuilder.Entity<vDepartment>().MapToStoredProcedures(s =>
           {
              s.Update(u => u.HasName("udp_Department_upd"));
              s.Delete(d => d.HasName("udp_Department_del"));
              s.Insert(i => i.HasName("udp_Department_ins").Result(r => r.ID, "NewID"));
           });
```

Insert stored procedure in database:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[udp_Department_ins]
  @ParentID  BIGINT,
  @Code      NVARCHAR(20),
  @SName     NVARCHAR(50),
  @Name      NVARCHAR(100),
  @CloseDate DATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NewID bigint; 

    INSERT INTO Department...
       SELECT @NewID AS NewID;
END;
```

Comment: When you define your stored proc mappings are there more options to define the parameters for each stored proc?

Comment: I have tried to describe so, but have the same error.               s.Insert(i => i.HasName("udp_Department_ins")
                       .Parameter(e => e.ParentID, "ParentID")
                       .Parameter(e => e.Code, "Code")
                       .Parameter(e => e.SName, "SName")
                       .Parameter(e => e.Name, "Name")
                       .Parameter(e => e.CloseDate, "CloseDate")
                       .Result(r => r.ID, "NewID")
                       );

Comment: You're trying to force the code first approach to a database first system.  In my experience mapping views to entities has always been uni-directional (database to POCO's) and has not involved inserts, updates or deletes using stored procs.  I suggest to create a POCO containing properties to map only the parameters of your insert stored proc.  However, this is not the code first way and adds unnecessary complexity to your data layer.

Comment: @Brad, That has not been true starting with version 6m which supports mapping views and sp's like Valerdos is doing in code-first. I have the same issue as Valerdos however and trying to find a solution to the view and sp having different parameter counts.

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public string ParentSName { get; set; }
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public string ParentName { get; set; }
```

to prevent ParentSName and ParentName to be offered as parameters to your stored procedure. Note that this does not mean these columns have to be actual computed columns in your database. Effectively it marks them as not updateble/readonly to EF.

I have not found a direct way to tell the mapping to ignore a parameter for a specific stored procedure, like in the edmx designer.

And do remember to add the computed columns as output of your stored procedure. This may or may not be required if these values change in the database on update.

```
s.Insert(i => i.HasName("udp_Department_ins").Result(r => r.ID, "NewID").Result(r => r.ParentName , "ParentName")
```